# Normalise an array of 3 vectors using Numba and Cuda

Tags: python, numba

I have a big array of 3D vectors which I want to normalise using numba and cuda. My array is a bit like this

```
vectors = []
vectors.append([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
vectors.append([-1.0, -1.0, -1.0])
```

As a beginner to numba and cuda, I have trawled unsuccessfully through blogs and tutorials trying to write a function which can normalise my array of vectors in parallel on the gpu.

Can someone please show me how to do it or point me to a useful article?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unit_vector()`:

```
import transformations as trafo
import numpy as np

vectors.append([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
vectors.append([-1.0, -1.0, -1.0])

normalized_vector = trafo.unit_vector(vectors, axis=1)
```